# onedrive refresh token error "invalid grant"

Tags: onedrive, refresh-token

While refreshing the onedrive  token before 5min of its expiry it is giving below error.
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "The user could not be authenticated or the grant is expired. The user must first sign in and if needed grant the client application access to the requested scope."
}

I am storing access token and  refresh token in DB.
What could be the possible chance for this.
Thanks in advance.